# How do I change two different icon using input type button based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have one input type button where I have to toggle the value with different icons and text, for example when the value is yes it must have an icon for YES with text. When the button value change to NO an icon changes with the text "no" next to it. I am failing to change those icons based on condition, I have tried to use CSS where my input I wrap it with  and use it.

```js
$('#yes').click(function(e) {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
    $(this).val('No');
  } else {
    $(this).val('Yes');
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="button"] {
  margin: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

span {
  position: relative;
}

span::after {
  font-family: 'Material Design Icons';
  content: "\F0138";
  font-size: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 1px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><input type="button" id="yes" value="Yes"/></span>
```

Comment: Can you post full css and code.

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL this what i have what i am struggling is to change icon based on condition

Answer (score 1):

Define two class on CSS. Find `span` using `parent()` and toggle class  to change image inside click event.

```
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('newclass');
```

Example:

```js
$('#yes').click(function(e) {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('newclass');
  if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
    $(this).val('No');
  } else {
    $(this).val('Yes');
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="button"] {
  margin: 10px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

span {
  position: relative;
}

span::after {
  font-family: 'Material Design Icons';
  content: "\F0138";
  font-size: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 1px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

span.newclass::before {
  font-family: 'Material Design Icons';
  content: "\0000";
  font-size: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 1px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<span><input type="button" id="yes" value="Yes"/></span>
```

Comment: Thank for your effort this is what I want